# MS Access Form with Webbrowser Control Popup New IE Window, Access 2010/VBA

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, ms-access, popup, webbrowser-control

I have struck with one issue not finding any workable solution. Googled a lot without any success…HELP PLEASE.

**Situation:** Using MS Access 2010, there is one Form with WebBrowser Control (Unbound) for conducting some search, when I click the results of the search a Pop-up new Internet Explorer window opens for the search result.

**Requirement:** I need “new Internet Explorer window” needs to be opened on existing WebBrowser Control..... NOT to open separately as new pop-up Internet Explorer window.

Kindly provide me solution (MS Access 2010/VBA) or workaround….

Regards,
Sandy

Answer (score 0):

Can you open the form that you are opening in the WebBrowser Control in a new browser window outside of the application in order to test something.  Check to see, if when you open the url, and then invoke the search, if the results open in a new window for that browser.  If so, then check the target of the form within the first screen to get the name of the window that the page is trying to open the results in.  If the target is specified, then you will need to write code to remove it when the page loads.

Comment: Thanks for provide you comments
I am not able find the URL the follows on Clicking.... or before opening Internet Explore.... if any we could any capture redirecting URL before click then... it is possible to set existing webbrowser control to navigate that URL

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the new web address to your webbrowser control. something like this. Note it has to include equal sign and a hyper-link surrounded by quote.

```
Private Sub WebBrowser34_Click()
    Me.WebBrowser34.ControlSource = "='www.google.co.uk'"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Krish,
Yes you are right but here are two thing to control/Get.
1. Hyper-link under the clicked item in webrowser control
2. Stopping to open new IE Window
Then we can use the method you suggest... please provide help for above to tasks.